# preg_replace doesn't display a text without url

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Good evening..I am able to change the url text into a link successfully but am having problems displaying a text without a url in it..It just doesn;t show because it doesn't have a url in it...

Have tried and tried .Please help me .Thanks

```
    <?php 
$textorigen = $row_get_tweets['tweet'];

// URL starting with http://
$reg_exUrl = "/(^|\A|\s)((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}   (\/\S*)?)/";
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $textorigen, $url)) {

 // make the urls hyper links
 $text_result=preg_replace( $reg_exUrl, "$1<a href=\"$2\">$2</a> ", $textorigen );
 $textorigen=$text_result;

 } else {

 // if no urls in the text just return the text
 $text_result=$textorigen;
 }   

  // URL starting www.
  $reg_exUrl = "/(^|\A|\s)((www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\/\S*)?)/";
  if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text_result, $url)) {

   // make the urls hyper links
   $text_result=preg_replace( $reg_exUrl, "$1<a href=\"http://$2\">$2</a>",    $text_result );
   $textorigen=$text_result;

  echo $textorigen;
   }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About the regex pattern:** It's very difficult to find the best pattern that describes efficiently an url (a compromise between accuracy and performance). This is the reason why a way consists to use a basic description of an URL to do that.

**About the code**: You can do the same in a more efficient way parsing the string only once with `preg_replace_callback`, example:

```
$textorigen = <<<'DATA'
abcd http://example.com efgh (ftps://example2.com/) ijkl www.example3.com
DATA;

$pattern = '~(?<=^|\s|\pP)(?:(ht|f)tps?://|www\.)\S+(?<![^\PP?/])(?=\s|$|\pP)~i';

$textorigen = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) {
                   $link = ($m[1])? $m[0] : 'http://' . $m[0];
                   return '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $link . '</a>'; },
                                    $textorigen);
echo $textorigen;
```

pattern description:

```
~                  #  pattern delimiter
(?<=^|\s|\pP)      #  lookbehind : preceded by the start of the string
                   # or a whitespace character or a punctuation character
(?:                #  non capturing group
    (ht|f)tps?://  #  scheme
  |                #  OR
    www\.          #  www.
)
\S+                #  one or more non whitespace characters 
(?<![^\PP?/])      #  that don't end with a punctuation character
                   # except "?" and "/"
(?=\s|$|\pP)       #  followed by a whitespace, the end of the string
                   # or a punctuation character
~i                 #  end delimiter, the pattern is case insensitive
```

Comment: Thank you very much..Am a newbie tried using the code..cOULDN'T GET IT TO WORK..how do I use it..Thanks

Comment: Okay Thanks will be waiting for it

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to test with `preg_match` before using `preg_replace`. `preg_replace` only replaces if there is a match.

Therefore your `if-then-else` structure can be simplified to something like:

```
$replaced = preg_replace($regex,$replacement,$original);
```